# Android eglSwapBuffers - manual control? (Android)

Tags: android, rendering, buffer, opengl-es-2.0, game-loop

My understanding is that eglSwapBuffers is called automatically every frame when using a GLSurfaceview, so:

```
onDrawFrame()
{

//Your drawing code here

//system swaps buffers automatically

}
```

is there any way at all that I can either disable this behaviour and call eglSwapBuffers myself/manually at the end of each onDrawFrame() or supress it when I need to (ie, let it run when I want it to but stop it from running when I need to).

If possible, I would be grateful if someone could explain how this can be achieved (if possible) when using both RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY & RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY

Of course, my understanding may be wrong, so please correct me if it is :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GLSurfaceView` isn't particularly flexible.  It'd be nice if `onDrawFrame` returned a "do draw" boolean; then you'd have a bit more flexibility in how you arrange your game loop.  `GLSurfaceView` doesn't work that way, though, so your options are limited.

You have two basic approaches if you want to avoid rendering every frame:

(1) Use `RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY`, and only request render when you know you will want to swap buffers when `onDrawFrame` completes.  This is pretty much what you want to do anyway if your game logic doesn't run on the render thread and you're not trying to run at 60fps.

(2) Download the source for `GLSurfaceView`, merge it into your app, and modify it to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks @fadden I'm just going with RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY at the moment, although I like the idea of modifying GLSurfaceView, that may be something I look into in the future.  Cheers.

Comment: Also worth a look: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops

Comment: Interesting, an 'official' article on Android Game Loops, never seen that before, I'll have a read - good find!